# CSS to grey a checkbox image if unchecked

Tags: html, css

CSS of the following is used to replace the regular checkbox element with checked/unchecked images.

```css
.ckbx {
  display:none;
}
.ckbx + label {
  background:url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/17/40/checkbox-152188_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.ckbx:checked + label {
  background:url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/17/40/checkbox-152187_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;          
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
<label for="bike">I have a bike</label>
```

Instead of using two images I need to use only one image (checked).

For the unchecked state how can I use CSS **only** to gray the image?

Comment: Your intention isn't clear, do you want to use one image without both state images and just moving image as a sprite (like google "sprite checkbox css") or you just want one image and gray it out with a gradient overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `opacity`

```css
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx + label {
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/17/40/checkbox-152188_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.ckbx:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
<label for="bike">I have a bike</label>
```

Or a pseudo

```css
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx + label {
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/17/40/checkbox-152188_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.ckbx + label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.ckbx:checked + label::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
<label for="bike">I have a bike</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you already marked an answer, here's a solution which actually applies a grayscale to your image with good browser support.

---

We will use an **SVG** filter:

First we define the svg element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

After that it is pretty straightforward, you use the CSS `filter` property.

```
.ckbx:checked + label {
  filter: url('#grayscale');
}
```

For it to also work on FF you would need to use the whole SVG like this:

```
.ckbx:checked + label {
   filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx + label {
  background: url('http://fillmurray.com/200/200') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ckbx:checked + label {
  background: url('http://fillmurray.com/200/200') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
<label for="bike">I have a bike</label>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

---

If you want to provide further browser support you can apply the same property with different vendor prefixes and use the `greyscale` function that accepts a percentage or decimal value.

```
.ckbx:checked + label {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%); /* Or grayscale(1)*/
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx + label {
  background: url('http://fillmurray.com/200/200') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ckbx:checked + label {
  background: url('http://fillmurray.com/200/200') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
<label for="bike">I have a bike</label>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 greyscale:

```
.ckbx + label {
  background:url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/17/40/checkbox-152188_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
.ckbx:checked + label {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 filters you could achieve this, but it wouldn't work in older browsers like internet explorer, see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

```css
.ckbx {
  display:none;
}
.ckbx + label {
 
  background-image: url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.ckbx:checked + label {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
<label for="bike">I have a bike</label>



<input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="plane">
<label for="plane">I have a bike</label>
```